# how to update service worker when online and reloading the page

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Hello all I am having the following code to load the page on offline, I have a requirement where I need to cache few pages and exclude few from cache. The code I wrote is working fine but when ever I push any updates to the site it is loading from cache how to reload it from server instead of cache when online

I referred to this blog and sum up with some modifications

https://www.charistheo.io/blog/2021/03/cache-handling-with-service-workers-and-the-cache-api/

```
self.addEventListener("install", function (e) {
     self.skipWaiting();
     e.waitUntil(async function () {
     const cache = await caches.open("app");
     await cache.addAll([
        "/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
        "/ReportableEvent/Index",
        "/NearMissReport/Index",
        "/ReportableEvent/InternalReview?ReportableEventId=0"
     )];
    }());
});

var uncachedPaths = new Set(["/Reportable/Reports", "/Dashboard/Index"]);
self.addEventListener("fetch", async function (e) {
   if (e.request.method !== "GET") {
    return;
  }
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request, { ignoreSearch: true }).then(async cachedResponse => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
            return cachedResponse;
        }
        else {
            if (e.request.url.includes("service-worker.js") && !navigator.onLine) {
                return;
            }

            // Fetch the requested resource from the network if it does not exist in the cache.
            const networkResponse = await fetch(e.request);

            // Response needs to be cloned if going to be used more than once.
            const clonedResponse = networkResponse.clone();

            if (!uncachedPaths.has(new URL(e.request.url).pathname)) {
                // Save response to runtime cache for later use.
                const runtimeCache = await caches.open("app");
                runtimeCache.put(e.request, networkResponse);
            }
            // Respond with the cloned network response.
            return Promise.resolve(clonedResponse);
        }
    })
); 
});
```

Also is this correct to cache the page which has Query strings `"/ReportableEvent/InternalReview?ReportableEventId=0"`

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches how to serve files from cache and how to update/invalidate the cache. please, refer [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker).

Also, if you are updating your service worker js files and want to update the cache as well, try appending version to cache name. For instance,

```
var version = 1.0;
var cachename= 'app'+version;
```

And every time you update the file, you can increment the version. This way every updates makes it new cache and files are stored afresh in cache.

Comment: OK how to delete previous cache? Let' say I update it to 1.1 how to remove 1.0 which was cached

Comment: I could see an approach here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache